# Card returned AAC in second generate AC CID data even online host approved transaction

Tags: emv

We are performing VISA L3 Certification where Transaction approved by host simulator but declined by card. Furthermore, when i checked CVR it shows "issuer authentication failed". please anyone advise what could be the issue. Thanks in advance.

**VISA L3 TEST CASE OBJECTIVE:Ensure online approval for a card that requires Issuer Authentication to be performed successfully.**

**9F10 Issuer Application Data (IAD)
060112032800000F00564953414C335445535443415345**

**CardLog:**

Command GENERATE APPLICATION CRYPTOGRAM
80 AE 80 00 1D
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 34 80 80 00 80 00 06 34 23 10 23 00 BF 30 7F 54 00
Amount, Authorized (Numeric) [9F02] - 00 00 00 00 02 00
Amount, Other (Numeric) [9F03] - 00 00 00 00 00 00
Terminal Country Code [9F1A] - 06 34
Terminal Verification Results [95] - 80 80 00 80 00
Transaction Currency Code [5F2A] - 06 34
Transaction Date [9A] - 23 10 23
Transaction Type [9C] - 00
Unpredictable Number [9F37] - BF 30 7F 54
80 22 80 00 08 15 37 E5 ED 09 F8 39 BA 06 01 12
03 A0 00 00 0F 00 56 49 53 41 4C 33 54 45 53 54
43 41 53 45
Data Analysis
Tag 80 : Response Message Template Format 1
Length : 22
Value : 80 00 08 15 37 E5 ED 09 F8 39 BA 06 01 12 03 A0
00 00 0F 00 56 49 53 41 4C 33 54 45 53 54 43 41
53 45
SW1 SW2 = 90 00 => Successful
Command GENERATE APPLICATION CRYPTOGRAM
80 AE 40 00 27
30 30 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 34 80 80 00 80 00 06 34 23 10 23 00 BF 30 7F 54 C1 99 4C 32 00 00 00 00 00
Authorisation Response Code [8A] - 30 30
Amount, Authorized (Numeric) [9F02] - 00 00 00 00 02 00
Amount, Other (Numeric) [9F03] - 00 00 00 00 00 00
Terminal Country Code [9F1A] - 06 34
Terminal Verification Results [95] - 80 80 00 80 00
Transaction Currency Code [5F2A] - 06 34
Transaction Date [9A] - 23 10 23
Transaction Type [9C] - 00
Unpredictable Number [9F37] - BF 30 7F 54
Issuer Authentication Data [91] - C1 99 4C 32 00 00 00 00
80 22 00 00 08 16 BC 18 B5 B0 E2 42 AA 06 01 12
03 28 00 00 0F 00 56 49 53 41 4C 33 54 45 53 54
43 41 53 45
Data Analysis
Tag 80 : Response Message Template Format 1
Length : 22
Value : 00 00 08 16 BC 18 B5 B0 E2 42 AA 06 01 12 03 28
00 00 0F 00 56 49 53 41 4C 33 54 45 53 54 43 41
53 45
SW1 SW2 = 90 00 => Successful

**VISA L3 TEST CASE OBJECTIVE:Ensure online approval for a card that requires Issuer Authentication to be performed successfully.**

Comment: try to recalculate ARQC/ARPC manually and compare it with the one generated by card/issuer host (I assume you have clear MDK key for this). What looks a bit strange is that in CSU, 'Issuer approves online transaction' bit is not set, but I would rather expected it set. So, the value of CSU should look at least like 00800000 if we receive online response from the issuer

Answer (score 0):

You could have really put any effort to make the question more readable and maybe provide some information about the test case and card profile used.

Regardless, I have found it and from what I see, your Issuer Authentication Data is incorrect. You need to check your interface with host simulator/card scheme certification environment as this is the reason card rejects it.

Comment: Let me check with host simulator team, thanks for your support